# Is it possible divide an ArrayList by a double and create a new list?

Tags: java, list, function, arraylist, division

I'm in a tricky situation here. I need to divide a list for a number and return another list including these divisions. For the code below, the output is:

```
[29.0, 19.0, 12.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```

So I want to take this list and divide by an variable and return a new list like:

Considering A = 2 for this example;

```
[29.0, 19.0, 12.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0]/A = [14.5, 9.5, 6.0, 4.0, 2.5, 1.5]
```

Here is the code's part.

```
ArrayList<Double> espacamento_lado_a = new ArrayList<Double>();
espacamento_lado_a.add(esp10a);
espacamento_lado_a.add(esp12a);
espacamento_lado_a.add(esp16a);
espacamento_lado_a.add(esp20a);
espacamento_lado_a.add(esp25a);
espacamento_lado_a.add(esp32a);
System.out.println(espacamento_lado_a);
```

Comment: What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Create a new list, loop over the first list `espacamento_lado_a`, then divide each element by `A`, adding the result to the new list. That's what you need to do.

Comment: Convenção java: `espacamentoLadoA`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(Double d : espacamento_lado_a) {
    result.add(d/A);
 }
```

`result` is the new `ArrayList<Double>` that you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is very is with stream with out looping using **single code line** .

What i suggest is

```
double a=2.0;   
List<Double> newList=espacamento_lado_a.stream().map(e->e.doubleValue()/a).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you can see the output both are print.

this is full code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double a=2.0;   
    ArrayList<Double> espacamento_lado_a = new ArrayList<Double>();

    espacamento_lado_a.add(29.0);
    espacamento_lado_a.add(19.0);
    espacamento_lado_a.add(12.0);
    espacamento_lado_a.add(5.0);
    espacamento_lado_a.add(3.0);

    System.out.println(espacamento_lado_a);


List<Double> newList=espacamento_lado_a.stream().map(e->e.doubleValue()/a).collect(Collectors.toList());

      System.out.println(newList);
   }

}
```

[image: Output would be as follows]